# Error on calculating a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this function, and need to make a figure in Matlab , using `Mesh` function.

[image]

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(-2:0.5:2,-3:0.5:3);
 z=exp(abs.(-x))*(x.^5+y.^4)*sin(x.*y);
 figure(1);
 mesh(x,y,z);
 title('Mesh');
```

I wrote the following code, but I get error for the exp function, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
The error message.

[image]

Comment: Errors messages are descriptive and essential. Please share it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I've attached the error message).

Comment: its `abs(-x)`, not `abs.(-x)`

Comment: I've tried this, and it also gives error:

`Error in ex3 (line 2)` 


`z=exp(abs(-x))*(x.^5+y.^4)*sin(x.*y)`

Comment: If you want to compute e^(-|x|) the minus should be outside abs. Then you are missing 2 dots multiplying exp by the other two terms: z=exp(-abs(x)).*(x.^5+y.^4).*sin(x.*y)

Comment: It worked!
Now I understand where I failed, thanks).